# Fence post issue

Tags: java, for-loop

I am printing a grid that increments down each column and I need the last column not to have any commas. I am familiar with the classic fence post problem, and I know how to solve it with a basic loop. But I am lost when it comes to nested loops. Any ideas? Thanks

I have tried adding commas to the front instead of the back and planting a "post" before the loop starts, but it never works out.

Here's my code:

```
public class Printgrid{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        printGrid(3, 6);
    }

    public static void printGrid(int rows, int cols){
        for (int i = 1; i <=rows; i++){
            for (int j = i; j<=cols*rows; j=j+rows){
                System.out.print(", " + j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16
, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17
, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18
```

Comment: Change your loops so you are writing one line at a time. I suggest you do it for just the first line to start with if having one loop is simpler for you.  Once you have the first line working adding more lines is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to skip printing the first comma, so you can try something along the lines of this (as the body of the inner loop):

```
if (j > i) {  // i.e. if we are not on the first iteration
    System.out.print(", ");
}
System.out.print(j);
```

which produces:

```
1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16
2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17
3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I tried something like that already but for some reason my version didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a boolean flag.  That way, you can change the loop variables and conditions without breaking anything.

```
public static void printGrid(int rows, int cols){
    for (int i = 1; i <=rows; i++){
        boolean isFirst = true;
        for (int j = i; j<=cols*rows; j=j+rows){
            if (isFirst) {
              System.out.print(j);
              isFirst = false;
            }
            else {
               System.out.print(", " + j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to add a comma after the first element, provided there is another element is to use a variable.

```
String sep = "";
for (int j = i, lim = cols * rows; j <= lim; j += rows){
    System.out.print(sep + j);
    sep = ", ";
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with no reliance on any if statements. You can print out the first scenario, i, and then iterate through j = i + rows.

The problem has been broken down into initial operation, iterative operation, and final operation to address the unique scenarios that occur at the endposts.

```
public static void printGrid(int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        System.out.print(i); // initial operation
        for (int j = i + rows; j <= cols * rows; j = j + rows) {
            System.out.print(", " + j);
        } // iterative operation
        System.out.println(); // final operation
    }
}
```